# How do I reset my check engine light in my Kawasaki Z125?

Tags: motorcycle, cel, kawasaki

How do I reset my check engine light on my 2017 Kawasaki Z125

Answer (score 1):

Found a screenshot of the manual in Z125 owners forum that describes the steps.

[image: screenshot of manual]
[Link to original](https://www.z125owners.com/forum/electronics/5553-check-engine-light-reset.html)

> The service codes stored in memory of the ECU and can be erased with Kawasaki Diagnostic System (KDS Ver.3)
>
> If the Kawasaki Diagnostic System (KDS Ver.3) is not is not available, do the following procedures:
>
> 1. Turn on the ignition switch and start the engine.
> 2. Keep the idling speed more than 30 seconds.
> 3. Run the vehicle more than 5 minutes at a speed of 40 km/h (25 mph)
>    or more.
>    Be sure to keep the engine running during the procedures 2 and 3 for more than 10 minutes in total.
> 4. Turn the ignition switch off.
> 5. repeat the above procedures 3 times.
> 6. Start the engine and check that the yellow engine warning indicator (LED) goes off.

Don't own Z125, hope it works. But first, is the issue causing it to turn on fixed?